# sqlalchemy symmetric many to one friendship

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am attempting to model a friendship using SQLAlchemy ORM. The relationship that I am trying to model is symmetric. Similar to Facebook, if user a is to add user b, user b must approve that friendship request. My current model is as follows.

```
class User(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'User'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(35), unique=False)
  username = db.Column(db.String(25), index=True, unique=True)
  password = db.Column(db.String(35), unique=False)
  email = db.Column(db.String(35), unique=True)
  phone_number = db.Column(db.String(22))

  # define relationships
  requester = db.relationship('Relationship', foreign_keys='Relationship.requesting_user', backref='requester')
  receiver = db.relationship('Relationship', foreign_keys='Relationship.receiving_user', backref='received')

  def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % (self.username)


class Relationship(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'Relationship'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  requesting_user = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'))
  receiving_user = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("User.id"))
  status = db.Column(db.Integer)
  __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('receiving_user', 'requesting_user', name='_receiving_user_uc'), )
```

The model works, however, I don't think that it is properly modeled. Is it even required that I use a status? I'm assuming it can be modeled so that each friend relationship gets its own entry. Currently, a user can initiate a friend request with another user. When the other user approves the request, the status changes to accepted. I have looked a little into association tables but am not too sure how they would play into a model like this. Any advice on my current model and how it can be improved would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `Relationship` table is the association table in this case. The symmetry of the "friends" relationship is at direct odds with the asymmetry of the "friendship requests" relationship. I think you should separate the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among other things, you may want to learn about [association proxies](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html). An association proxy tells SQLAlchemy that you have a many-to-many relationship mediated by an intermediate table which may contain additional data. In your case, each `User` can send multiple requests and also receive multiple requests and `Relationship` is the mediating table which contains the `status` column as additional data.

Here is a variant of your code which stays relatively close to what you wrote:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    # The above is not necessary. If omitted, __tablename__ will be
    # automatically inferred to be 'user', which is fine.
    # (It is necessary if you have a __table_args__, though.)

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(35), unique=False)
    # and so forth

    requested_rels = db.relationship(
        'Relationship',
        foreign_keys='Relationship.requesting_user_id',
        backref='requesting_user'
    )
    received_rels = db.relationship(
        'Relationship',
        foreign_keys='Relationship.receiving_user_id',
        backref='receiving_user'
    )
    aspiring_friends = association_proxy('received_rels', 'requesting_user')
    desired_friends = association_proxy('requested_rels', 'receiving_user')

    def __repr__(self):
        # and so forth


class Relationship(db.Model):
    # __tablename__ removed, becomes 'relationship'
    # __table_args__ removed, see below

    requesting_user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'), primary_key=True)
    receiving_user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'), primary_key=True)
    # Marking both columns above as primary_key creates a compound primary
    # key, which at the same time saves you the effort of defining the
    # UNIQUE constraint in __table_args__
    status = db.Column(db.Integer)

    # Implicit one-to-many relations: requesting_user, receiving_user.
    # Normally it would be more convenient to define those relations on
    # this side, but since you have two outgoing relationships with the
    # same table (User), you chose wisely to define them there.
```

(Note how I ordered the lines slightly differently and how I used the `_id` suffix for foreign key columns while reserving the same name without the suffix for the corresponding `db.relationship`s. I would suggest that you adopt this style, too.)

Now you have a clean way to access incoming and outgoing friendship requests as well as the corresponding users directly from your `User` model. However, this is still less than ideal because you need to write the following code in order to get all *confirmed* friends of a user:

```
def get_friends(user):
    requested_friends = (
        db.session.query(Relationship.receiving_user)
        .filter(Relationship.requesting_user == user)
        .filter(Relationship.status == CONFIRMED)
    )
    received_friends = (
        db.session.query(Relationship.requesting_user)
        .filter(Relationship.receiving_user == user)
        .filter(Relationship.status == CONFIRMED)
    )
    return requested_friends.union(received_friends).all()
```

(I did not test this; you might need to also `join` with `User` in both queries in order for the `union` to work.)

To make things worse, the model name `Relationship` as well as the names of several members within the models don't seem to convey very well what they actually mean.

You can improve matters by removing `Relationship.status` and renaming `Relationship` to `FriendshipRequest`. Then, add a second `User`-to-`User` association model called `Friendship` and add a corresponding second set of `db.Relationship`s with `backref`s and `association_proxy`s to `User`. When somebody sends a friendship request, you file a record to `FriendshipRequest`. If the request is accepted, you remove the record and replace it with a new record in `Friendship`. This way, instead of using a status code, the status of a friendship is encoded by the table in which you store a pair of users. The `Friendship` model may look like this:

```
class Friendship(db.Model):
    user1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'), primary_key=True)
    user2_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'), primary_key=True)

    # Implicit one-to-many relations: user1, user2
    # (defined as backrefs in User.)
```

(Corresponding `db.relationship`s and `association_proxy`s in `User` are left as an exercise to the reader.)

This approach saves you half of the filtering operations when you need the confirmed friends of a user. Still, you need to make a `union` of two queries because your user can be either `user1` or `user2` in each instance of `Friendship`. This is inherently difficult because we are dealing with a reflexive symmetric relationship. I think it is possible to invent still more elegant ways to do it, but I think that would be complicated enough to warrant a new question here on Stack Overflow.